# Adding dynamically an object to a json file using jq in a bash script

Tags: bash, jq

Im trying to build dynamically a json using a bash script with a loop inside:

```
touch credScanSuppressionsFile.json
echo '{"tool": "Credential Scanner", "suppressions":[]}' | jq > credScanSuppressionsFile.json

webapp_name=customer-brasil-forms

for env in develop #staging demo preprod prod
do
    file='azure_portal_variables\'$env-$webapp_name.json
    echo $file
    jq --arg file $file '.suppressions += [{"file": $file, "_justification": "app setting file"}]' <<< "$(cat credScanSuppressionsFile.json)" > credScanSuppressionsFile.json
done
```

Everything looks like its working... but when you see the output:

```json
{
  "tool": "Credential Scanner",
  "suppressions": [
    {
      "file": "azure_portal_variables\\develop-customer-brasil-forms.json",
      "_justification": "app setting file"
    }
  ]
}
```

The desire output should be (**be aware of the filename with double slash**):

```json
{
  "tool": "Credential Scanner",
  "suppressions": [
    {
      "file": "azure_portal_variables\develop-customer-brasil-forms.json",
      "_justification": "app setting file"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Check your script with https://shellcheck.net and fix any issue it points out.

Comment: @LéaGris sorry, finally I have pasted the wrong scape formula... I have edited the code... Notice that now, the echo shows the correct file path but jq is resolving this with double slash... this is the original problem.

Comment: I think you are mistaken in your output desire. The backslash in the JSON string has to be escaped. If you pipe that output through `jq -r .suppressions[].file` you see that there is only a single backslash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the chosen code, at least a valid one for my case, is:

```
touch credScanSuppressionsFile.json
echo '{"tool": "Credential Scanner", "suppressions":[]}' | jq > credScanSuppressionsFile.json

webapp_name=customer-brasil-forms

for env in develop #staging demo preprod prod
do
    file=$env-$webapp_name.json
    echo $file
    jq --arg file $file '.suppressions += [{"file": $file, "_justification": "app setting file"}]' <<< "$(cat credScanSuppressionsFile.json)" > credScanSuppressionsFile.json
done
```

**I have realised that just using the name of the file is enough.**

Things to highlight is that @Armali is right, the json as it was (my supposed wrong result) is correct and the backslash should be scaped with double backslash and @LeaGris thanks for your help, but the code was correct after the edition, the errors you see its just info in case you want to use it.

```
touch credScanSuppressionsFile.json
echo '{"tool": "Credential Scanner", "suppressions":[]}' | jq > credScanSuppressionsFile.json

webapp_name=customer-brasil-forms

for env in develop staging demo preprod prod
do
    file='azure_portal_variables\'$env-$webapp_name.json
    echo $file
    jq --arg file $file '.suppressions += [{"file": $file, "_justification": "app setting file"}]' <<< "$(cat credScanSuppressionsFile.json)" > credScanSuppressionsFile.json
done
```

**This code is also correct**

Answer (score 0):

Please do the shellcheck as I recommended you to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73248565/adding-dynamically-an-object-to-a-json-file-using-jq-in-a-bash-script#comment129362287_73248565)

```
$ shellcheck myscript
 
Line 8:
for env in develop #staging demo preprod prod
           ^-- SC2043 (warning): This loop will only ever run once. Bad quoting or missing glob/expansion?
 
Line 10:
    file='azure_portal_variables\'$env-$webapp_name.json
                                ^-- SC1003 (info): Want to escape a single quote? echo 'This is how it'\''s done'.
 
Line 12:
    jq --arg file $file '.suppressions += [{"file": $file, "_justification": "app setting file"}]' <<< "$(cat credScanSuppressionsFile.json)" > credScanSuppressionsFile.json
>>                                                                                                            ^-- SC2094 (info): Make sure not to read and write the same file in the same pipeline.
>>                                                                                                                                              ^-- SC2094 (info): Make sure not to read and write the same file in the same pipeline.

$
```

Once you have fixed all the shell issues, then we can start helping you about the `jq` issue.